# Mother's physiological response to baby crying

Tags: reproduction, psychology

I have read several articles [1,2] that talks about the physiological response in mothers when their babies cry. Is there any studies performed and published that show that this is not true ?

1. https://www.sciencenews.org/blog/growth-curve/how-baby-cries-bore-mom%E2%80%99s-brain
2. https://www.livescience.com/36964-baby-cries-women-men-brains.html

Comment: Hello Noor. It is better to cite a peer reviewed publication when citing references. Anyway, to prove that something exists you just need a single evidence; to disprove the existence of something you have to exhaust all possibilities. First, step to verify the authenticity of a research is to check if it is designed and conducted properly. Then you repeat the experiment and see if it is reproducible. Having said that, I would insist that you should also try looking for articles that dispute this claim. Here, we appreciate if users show some effort from their side before asking.

Comment: Some women do not respond emotionally and physiolocically to their own crying infants. It is highly abnormal, and deleterious to the emotional development of the child. Women are hard wired to resopnd to their infant crying. If it weren't true, we would not have survived as a species.

Comment: @WYSIWYG, i take note of your advise, thanks